# WPF Controls not releasing memory

Tags: wpf, memory, garbage-collection

I am having a strange behaviour in a small WPF application. I have one button on a Window and it opens another window as a Dialog which has a few controls which are added dynamically. While doing that I keep an eye on its memory usage which increases (sysinternal procexp). But when I close that Window the memory usage does not come back.

Comment: It's not in the interest of the GC to release memory back to the OS when the system is not low on memory, so external measurements of the application's memory usage are not an accurate reflection of how much memory is actually being consumed.  For that, you'll want to get .NET specific memory profiling tools.

Comment: But I have tried explicitly calling GC.Collect so the garbage collector runs even if freeing up the memory is not required. That does not make any difference.

Comment: Most likely some stuff is not getting disposed.

Comment: @Akif, forcing collection may free up memory on the managed heap, but it does not necessary release the memory allocated for the managed heap back to the OS.  It makes sense for the GC to hold onto the memory its already allocated to the heap, as long as the system is not low on memory.

Comment: @Dan Bryant your statement seems logical. When I close the last opened window and then reopen it, the previously opened window's destructor is called. Which proved that GC runs when it thinks it should free up some memory because the object being created will need more memory. How do I make sure that my objects which are being closed on the UI do get collected by GC immedaitely.

Comment: I created this small application to make myself sure about the behaviour of WPF controls in applications. My main problem is that we have an ASP.NET application which further does some rendering of WPF controls. After a few requests from multiple users the memory of the server increases exponentially and server crashes. We are sure the culprit is the WPF part of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using this tool http://memprofiler.com/
I had some similar experiences in WPF and win forms.
It will probably be something not being disposed as previously suggested but memprofiler will show you exactly what it is and make finding the solution really easy.